# Height Using 100 % of Parent Div

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="img-blocks">
  <div class="img-blocks-header"></div>
  <div class="img-blocks-images"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-blocks{
    width:984px ;
    height:265px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    border-radius:7px ;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.img-blocks-header{
    width:100% ;
    height: 33px;
    background: #c8c2c2;
    border-radius:7px 7px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
.img-blocks-images{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    border:1px dotted black;


}
```

I want that `div` with class `.img-blocks-images` use `100%` of available height i.e. after deducting height of `.img-block-header` from parent .
Don't want to use `100%` height of its parent div `.img-blocks`.

Comment: if your heights are fixed, why not use `height: (265-33)px` ?

Comment: `height: calc(100% - 33px);`

Comment: @abhitalks there's not enough support for that right now, unfortunately

Comment: If your wrapper DIV is `.img-blocks` why dont you set that to have a percentage height and width and from there you can set a percentage height and width on the inner sections and they will get that percentage from there wrapper?

Comment: @vlrprbttst if we exclude `IE<9` and `Safari<5.1` it is well supported (using vendor prefixes)

Comment: @vlrprbttst: As per [(this)](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc), nearly all modern browsers now support this. So we may say that it *"has enough support right now"*.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan what about mobile? android browser is supporting it only on KitKat

Comment: @vlrprbttst a fallback is required anyway. I would set `height: 232px`. Note that in this specific example `calc()` is not necessary at all

Answer (score 0):

You can add `height:100%` to `.img-blocks-images` which you already have. But this will make it overflow the parent div. So add `overflow:hidden` to parent div.

This will work even if the heights change dynamically

Here is the fiddle

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/28Y8c/)

Answer (score 0):

If `.img-blocks-header` has a fixed height, you can absolute position it and and give `.img-blocks-images` a top padding of 33px (header height) plus the intended padding (10px) -> 43px. This way, the `.img-blocks-images` 100% height will always match its parent.

A demo fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lv6hF/